# Closure of category of sheaves under inverse limits.

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory

How do I show that the category of sheaves on a space $X$ taking values in , a category $K$ admitting inverse limits, admits inverse limits?

The limit is a presheaf, I tried to show that it is also a sheaf but I cannot establish the existence of the morphisim from any given object $T$ in $K$ to $F(U)$ satisfying the definition of a sheaf (as in the stacks project for example).

Comment: Limits commute with limits, so a limit of equalizers is an equalizer

Comment: Once you interpret a sheaf as an equalizer and then interpret an equalizer as a limit , this becomes a trivial fact.